# How to bottle Hard Cider

Tags: bottling, cider

I made hard cider this way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G25FFvCpNoQ

except I also added cranberries, a couple tablespoons of sugar, and cinnamon. I was wondering after how long it will be done and if, when, and how I should bottle it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did everything as done in the video.

Simplest way to carbonate is to just put the cap on the bottle once the bubbling has slowed and the balloon shrinks. When the plastic bottle gets hard or starts to swell release some pressure. You can the refrigerate and serve from the bottle, taking care when serving not to disturb the yeast on the bottom. I wouldn't recommend this way unless you can check on it every few hours.

Or you can let fermentation complete and let yeast settle, then transfer to a clean bottle, add 3/4 oz corn sugar and seal bottle, leave to ferment again making carbonation (7-14days). Chill and serve

Comment: How long should I let it ferment?

Comment: @TalC when the balloon goes limp but not flat with just a pin hole. 7-14 days.

Comment: Would anything after that help with taste due to using rapid rise yeast?

Comment: @TalC it will have a slight bread note, when done right is simular to Apple pie. Aging helps mellow flavors.

Comment: Ok thanks! Does aging increase alcohol content?

Comment: @TalC no, it will mellow harsh alcohol flavors though. Higher tollerant yeast, and more sugars give higher ABV. Bread yeast is only tollerant to about 5% ABV